# How to display content from one xaml inside another

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I'm trying to reference a view2 inside view1. The problem is that view2 is in different project, so I can't really use the following:

```
            <local:View2Name DataContext="{Binding XZValue}" />
```

It is in different namespace so which tag should I be using and what to do?

Comment: The project is referred in project 1?

Answer (score 0):

First make sure that the project where view2 is in is referenced (see comment of Eldho)

Then you should link the namespace where view2 is in in the top of the file

`xmlns:view2namespace="clr-namespace:Project2.Views;assembly=Project2"`

where "Project2.Views" is the namespace and "Project2" is the project you can choose "view2namespace" yourself but it has to be unique

Now you should be able to use your view like this

```
<view2namespace:view2 DataContext="{Binding XZValue}" />
```

Comment: Why can you not reference it? Is it because Project1 is already referenced in Project2?